# trying 2 save data cassandra in springboot with optional keyword,as the field may contain null values,its giving me InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring-boot, scala, cassandra, null, option-type

Exception in thread "Thread-10" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown type [class java.util.Optional] for property [product] in entity [in.happysellers.hdb.gold.orders.DummyTable]; only primitive types and Collections or Maps of primitive types are allowed

i have manually inserted values in cassandra table, and try to fetch by query, it is giving me right records, then why i am not able to save records through code using optional. i think there should be some annotation to use optional values in repo files, which i am unable to find.

```
package in.happysellers.hdb.gold.orders

import in.happysellers.utils.DateTimeUtils
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.{Column, PrimaryKeyColumn, Table}
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable

import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.util.Optional
import javax.persistence._


@Table("dummy_table")
class DummyTable private {

  @Id
  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "user_id", `type` = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  var userId: Long = _

  @Column("product")
  @Nullable
  var product: Optional[String] = _

  @Column("product_details")
  @Nullable
  var productDetails: Optional[String] = _

  @Column("quantity")
  var quantity: Int = _

  @Column("cost")
  var cost: Float = _

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "created_at", `type` = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
  var createdAt: Timestamp = _

  def this(userId: Long, product: Optional[String],productDetails: Optional[String], quantity: Int, cost: Float) {
    this()
    this.userId = userId
    this.product = product
    this.productDetails = productDetails
    this.quantity = quantity
    this.cost = cost
    this.createdAt = DateTimeUtils.currentTimestamp
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating a Type mismatch for the value in the column `product`; this is because an Optional variable is passed, instead of a string.

```java
   this.product = product.orElse("NA")
```

That way, if no product is provided, the default `NA` (or whatever string you defined) will be assigned.